# Guard clauses in void methods

Tags: coding-style

The consensus seems to be that it's better to put an if statement guard clause at the top of a method rather than using an if else statement.

However, how can this be done with a **void method** and **Console.WriteLine()** to display an error? I would argue that example 2 is pretty ugly, especially if you have to validate multiple parameters and display separate errors when checking user input in a command line application for example.

I'm not an advanced programmer, but I'd argue the 1st example is more readable in this scenario. With that said, I can understand why people dislike complicated nested if statements.

#### 1. If else statement

```
private static void ValidateInput(string[] files, char[] password)
{
    if (files != null)
    {
        if (password.Length > 0)
        {
            ... // 20 lines here
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Please enter a password.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Please select a file.");
    }
}
```

#### 2. If statement

```
private static void ValidateInput(string[] files, char[] password)
{
    if (files == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Please enter a password.");
        return;
    }
    if (password.Length == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Please select a file.");
        return;
    }
    ... // No indentation for the next 20 lines.
}
```

Comment: The second example looks much better, IMO. The fundamental mistake here is that your business logic (validation of files, passwords) is intertwined with user interface logic (printing messages to the console). This is what exceptions are for. `ValidateInput` should through an exception. A separate component, higher up, should catch that exception and react appropriately. This can include responding by logging to the console.

Comment: Alternative consideration: on a form, it's much nicer to shower a user all the mistakes, rather than having them submit over and over, and revealing only one mistake at a time (which ever your logic caught first, short-circuiting the rest). In that case, you should make a `ValidationResult` object, and have each `if` statement staple a new `ValidationError` object to it. Your function should then return this `ValidationResult`, so that a higher component can then either proceed (if there's no errors), or display all the errors (e.g. make all the errored form fields red).

Comment: What action is performed in the 20 lines omitted?

Comment: Or, as an alternative to Alexander's good comment: scratch the `void` and return an error code instead. It's a question of preference and api-design. However, don't mix user interface with logic.

Comment: @whatsisname I just modified an example I found elsewhere on StackExchange, but it could be things like more validation and then calls to another method.

Comment: @mtj I'm not sure what you mean since the validation of user input has to be put somewhere. That's all this type of method is doing. It's validating user input before making calls to another method for the logic.

Comment: Yes, the *validation* is ok there, but not the *output* of the error message.

Answer (score 10):

There's no great consensus on this, and it can vary from language to language.

That said, I'd encourage you to prefer the quick return pattern (#2 in the OP). Separating the condition from the error message make them hard to keep together in your head, which causes bugs and makes the code harder to read.

The nested conditional version also isn't great when you have many conditions. You'll end up with different guidelines for different situations, causing confusion and friction and increased cognitive load since there isn't a single pattern to identify.

Comment: You make a good point. I'll start adopting the 2nd style.

Answer (score 2):

[Good answer here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/420469) already. I would like to suggest going a step further and refactor this to something along the lines of:

```
private static void ValidateInput(string[] files, char[] password)
{
     string message = GetValidationMessage(files,password);
     if(message.Length>0)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Error: " + message);
     }
}

private static string GetValidationMessage(string[] files, char[] password)
{
    if (files == null)
    {
        return "Please enter a password.";
    }
    if (password.Length == 0)
    {
        return "Please select a file.";
    }
    // ... 
}
```

(in C#, of course).

This is more DRY (since it does not repeat the `Console.WriteLine` statement multiple times), and makes a clear separation between the responsibilities of *validating* and processing the validation's result.

Alternatively, one could use exceptions here, but for a validation, failing is not really an "exceptional" situation, so it is debatable if this brings any real benefits.

In case you want to collect and print out several validation messages at once, you could refactor this to

```
private static void ValidateInput(string[] files, char[] password)
{
     var messages = GetValidationMessages(files,password);
     foreach(string message in messages)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Error: " + message);
     }
}

private static IEnumerable<string> GetValidationMessages(string[] files, char[] password)
{
    if (files == null)
    {
        yield return "Please enter a password.";
    }
    if (password.Length == 0)
    {
        yield return "Please select a file.";
    }
    // ... 
}
```

This makes most sense when the different validation rules are mostly independent from each other, so one root cause does not does not produce half a dozen subsequent messages.

Comment: Note that `GetValidationMessage` could return an **array** of strings, one for each error.  In which case append an "s" to the name.

Comment: @user949300: an `IEnumerable` is more flexible than an array with less code, it lets the caller decide if they want an array or something else. And I appended already an "s" to `GetValidationMessage` in that second variant, didn't you notice?

Comment: The problem with `IEnumerable` (and some similar Java classes, though some of them have a `hasNext()`) is that it doesn't have an easy way to count the number of errors.  So, **the most important question, "can I continue?"**, is hard to answer.

Comment: @user949300: if you read my former comment again, more thoroughly, you may find out by yourself why this is a misconception.

Answer (score 1):

That it's a `void` method is irrelevant. We still have to return or throw on each branch; we still want to make early exit conditions orthogonal (apart from other concerns, the alternative could lead to more cases, more lines of code & deeper nesting); we still don't want to execute any code unnecessarily. If anything, `void` methods make this pattern even easier, because we don't need a sensible return value when you don't want to throw an error or exception.

Answer (score 0):

A series of guard clauses forms a **list**. A single nested if structure forms a **tree**.

The former is a one-dimensional data structure; the latter is two-dimensional.

The mental effort to understand a one-dimensional structure is comparable to that required to understand a two-dimensional structure only for trivial `n` (as in your example, where `n` is 2). If you were validating a series of 10 fields, a series of guard clauses would still be easy to reason about, while a nested if structure would be nearly incomprehensible-- you'd spend most of your effort scrolling up and down and matching up brackets. It would be very easy to put logic into the wrong `else` block because it is so far removed, literally, from the source code that governs when it executes.

Since a one-dimensional structure scales better, I see the guard clause approach as more maintainable and extensible.

That does not always mean it is preferable. A nested if structure may be clearer for logic where `n` is small and the code is not likely to change.